# Proving an identity in a quasi-cocommutative Hopf Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(H,\mu\nu,\Delta,\epsilon,S,S^{-1},R)$ be a quasi-cocommutative Hopf algebra with an invertible antipode. Consider the element $u \in H$ given by: $$u = \sum_iS(t_i)s_i$$

Where $$R=\sum_i s_i \otimes t_i$$ and we set $$R^{-1}=\sum_i \bar{s_i} \otimes \bar{t_i}$$. In this case, the element $u$ is invertible in $H$ and $u^{-1}=\sum_i S^{-1}(\bar{t_i})s_i$ and for all $x \in H$ we have $S^2(x)=uxu^{-1}$.

During the proof that $S^2(x)u=ux$ $\forall x \in H$ it states that:

$$\sum_{i,(x)}S^2(x''')S(x'')ux'=ux$$

I'm having problems deriving this equality... does the invertibility of $u$ mean that it is in center? Even so, I'd appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $R = \sum_{i} s_i\otimes t_i$?

Comment: Indeed I do, thanks

Comment: So, since the proof of this relation (equation (4.6) on page 181 of Kassel, I believe?) has a few steps, could you point out which of the steps you are unsure of? It'll be easier to answer your question precisely if more context is given.

Comment: I got it, haha, thanks though man you are the bomb!!!